# Amazon Cognito User Lock Out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito Identity with user pools for sign-up and sign-in. I need to lockout user on third consecutive invalid attempts and send email, Is there any way I can handle it using Cognito triggers, Cloudwatch alarm or should I implement our own logic for this scenario